# php - laravel base_convert() not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a controller where i have used [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function. But instead of converting it, it shows only input value not converted value in output.

Eg: for the below controller it's showing only the `$currentID`, not the converted one. Why is this happening? If anyone find the problem, please share it with us.

```
public function getShortUrl(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[                      
            'url' => 'required|unique:urls'                             
            ]);
        $url = new Url();
        $url->url = $request->Input(['url']);  
        $url->save();
        $currentId = $url->id;
        $url_code=base_convert($currentId,16,8);
        $url->code ='http://go.'.$url_code;
        $url->save();
    //  return redirect('getURL');
    }
```

Comment: what's your id like, what's the  base of currentId?

Comment: look's like your using normal base 10 integer as $currentId, if that's the case then 2nd parameter in base_convert should be 10

Comment: yes i'm using normal base 10 integer and I have changed the second integer to 10 also,but nothing changed actually, same output I'm getting!

Comment: you also have to convert the number to string ( $currentId )